# Spring Integration XML - Unmarshall before send to channel

Tags: spring-integration

In my application i have a router that dinamically send XML tag to the appropiate channel:

```
<!-- Route each tag to the appropiate channel -->
<int-xml:xpath-router id="router" input-channel="routerChannel" evaluate-as-string="true">
    <int-xml:xpath-expression expression="concat(name(./node()), 'Channel')" />
</int-xml:xpath-router>
```

Using this XML this route each tag to `serviceChannel` and `activityChannel`

```
<root>
  <service attr1="x" attr2="y" />
  <activity anotherAttr="W" />
</root>
```

My service activator(S) POJO are something like this:

```
class Service {
  private String attr1;
  private String attr2;

  /* Setter and getter omitted */
}
```

And this is the applicationContext.xml configuration:

```
<!-- Service activators --> 
  <int:service-activator input-channel="serviceChannel" method="schedule">
    <bean class="it.mypkg.Service" />
  </int:service-activator>
```

The router send the entire `Node` to `bean` and i will need to extract the attributes "by hand".

**There is a way to "unmarshall" the `Node` so in `attr1` and `attr2` i will get the value provided in XML ?**

Usally i do this with a simple Unmarshaller (using JAXB) and adding the annotations `@XmlRootElement`, `@XmlAttribute` and so on.

I think before pass to POJO i will need to use SI-XML UnmarshallingTransformer but i really dont know how to do this... moreover this should be "enough general" to handle all tags (sure, all POJO classes like `Service` and `Activity` will have `@XmlAttribute` etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [Unmarshalling Transformer](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/xml.html#xml-unmarshalling-transformer) and then route on the unmarshalled objects.

Comment: This is what i was in mind but i dont understand some thing in unmarshallingTransformer, for example the property contextPath that in the link have a value of org.example. You can provide me a little example of how to implement it ?

Comment: The context-path is simply the package where your JAXB annotated classes are. See the javadocs for `JAXBContext.newInstance()` and the [spring reference manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/oxm.html#oxm-jaxb).